# Semantic UI, positioning labels

Tags: html, css, checkbox, semantic-ui

I'm using a checkbox in Semantic UI.  I would like to switch the position of the label and the input but it's proving to be kind of a pain. I am using the toggle checkbox.

```
<div class="ui toggle checkbox">
  <input id="privacy" type="checkbox" checked="checked">
  <label for="privacy">Public</label>
</div>
```

Semantic UI checkboxes docs are here: http://semantic-ui.com/modules/checkbox.html#/definition

If I switch the input and label in the html, the toggle function stops working.  I can't even seem to position the elements relatively... is there some easy class I can add or something that will enable the input and label to have switched positioning while still maintaining the functionality of the red-green toggle?

Thanks..

Update:  I'm working on a fiddle here:  this INCLUDES the semantic ui css and js.

http://jsfiddle.net/3xkrx/30/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what you can do:

```
.ui.toggle.checkbox label {
    padding-left:0;
    padding-right:4em;
}

.ui.checkbox input,
.ui.toggle.checkbox label:before {
    left:auto;
    right:0;
}

.ui.toggle.checkbox label:after {
    left:auto;
    right:1.75em;
    transition:background 0.3s ease 0s, right 0.3s ease 0s;
}

.ui.toggle.checkbox input:checked + label:after {
    left:auto;
    right:0.5em;
    transition:background 0.3s ease 0s, right 0.3s ease 0s;
}
```

The checkbox is basically just styled to look like that. The actual `<input type="checkbox" />` is transparent.

Comment: Thanks for helping.  I pasted this into my fiddle with no luck, I'm going to tweak it a bit.. Do you have it working?

Comment: How do you even know how to do this?! Can you write a book so I can read it? all these before and after css rules boggle me.  THANKYOU

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you still have this problem but I found a sort of solution.
in my case I have a table that looks like

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><label for="A_ID">select A</label></td>
    <td>
        <div class="ui checkbox">
          <input id="A_ID" type="checkbox">
          <label for="A_ID"></label>
        </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Because I have a label behind it the code it works (without Javascript).

little example http://jsfiddle.net/3xkrx/162/

Answer (score 1):

So you want the label on the left? Use a float on the label.

I have placed the class - `.custom` - on the div, but you could apply to an existing class :)

[Have an example!](http://jsbin.com/tewowa/1/edit)

HTML

```
<div class="ui toggle checkbox custom">
```

CSS

```
.custom label {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 5px 0;
}
```

Comment: This was the first thing I tried, unfortunately this doesn't work.  It may work in a fiddle, but semantic UI has more CSS in the 'ui toggle checkbox' that inhibits this form working.  Thanks for your submission though.