# semantic ui react, how to change label position?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, semantic-ui

Is it possible to change label position from right side to the left? I've tried to use float: left  but it doesn't work.

```
import {Radio } from "semantic-ui-react"
<Radio label="in progress" toggle />
```

[image]

Comment: A lot depends on the html too, not just the css. Post your html/css and we'll be able to help more.

Comment: @rrd this is it , just importing component and adding props

Comment: Have you [tried this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25355614/semantic-ui-positioning-labels)?

Comment: @Tholle seems for semantic ui react  it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Can be done, have to do it a bit hacky way. Here is how it can be done.

```
const RadioExampleRadio = () => (
  <div class="radio-block">
    {" "}
    <label className="radio-label">Radio Label</label>
    <Radio />
  </div>
);
```

Have to add some css to make it look better

```
.radio-block{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.radio-label{
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

From semantic's documentation, there doesn't seem to be any comment on changing the position of the label on the radio button. It can be done this way though.